# ngClass if string length

Tags: angular

I want to add a class to my div if a string is larger than 10 characters, I try this but didn't work

```
<div class="page-heading" ngClass="{'hidden-lines':post.title.length > 10}">
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to box it using `[]` so that becomes `[ngClass]`. This notation is used for expression binding.

```
<div class="page-heading" [ngClass]="{'hidden-lines':post.title.length > 10}">
```

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative would be the following:

```
<div class="page-heading" [class.hidden-lines]="hideLines">
```

in component:

```
get hideLines(): boolean {
   return this.post.title.length > 10;
}
```

This is specially util when you need to control a single class depending on a condition